# How to increase the maximum title length from 100 to 200 in Testlink

Tags: testcase, testlink

In "Create Test case" option, I want to give test case name length more than 100 characters. But it takes only 100 characters and trims the rest of the name. I want to change that limit to 200 characters.

Kindly guide me as in which file in TestLink-1.9.7 I need to make changes and where?

Comment: Something like [this](http://forum.testlink.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=6164)?

Answer (score 2):

That's easy!

Please read the guidelines from:
http://www.embeddedsystemtesting.com/2011/11/how-to-change-test-case-title-in-test.html

In general what you need to do is modification of DB design for one field and modification of one file:

1. In Database: change designed value of Name field in nodes_hierarchy table to 255 (default is 100)
2. Modify /gui/templates/input_dimensions.conf such way

   Search and increase

   - SRS_TITLE_MAXLEN=255 /default is 100
   - REQ_SPEC_TITLE_MAXLEN=255/default is 100
   - TESTCASE_NAME_MAXLEN=255 /default is 100

In case you need to increase the limits for other items, you can do the changes described in step 2 above for other parameters as well, like: TESTPLAN_NAME_MAXLEN, CONTAINER_NAME_MAXLEN etc

For use case of creating test cases using import you need also to modify the following file: /cfg/const.inc.php

- $g_field_size->node_name = 255
- $g_field_size->testcase_name = 255
- etc (depending on which items' limits you want to increase - names of test cases, test suites, requirements and so on)